# Showing hidden content once jQuery.countdown is finished

Tags: jquery

I'm using the [jQuery.countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) plugin to show a countdown on a page.

Once the countdown is finished I want to hide the countdown and show a hidden div.

I have managed to do so, but only if you have the page visible on the browser while the countdown is running. If I try to access the page once the `event.strftime` has passed, all I see is the static countdown with 0   days/hours/minuets/seconds, and I'm trying to get the same result as when viewing the page (hiding the countdown and showing the hidden div)

This is the code I'm using:

```js
$("span#limit").countdown("2019-09-12 16:00:00", function(event) {
  $(this).text(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
}).on('finish.countdown', function() {
  $(this).hide(200);
  $('.div').show(800);

});
```

```css
.div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<span id="limit"></span>
<div class="div">
  Hidden content
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`event.elapsed`](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#elapse-mode)

```js
function finish() {
  $('span#limit').hide(200);
  $('.div').show(800);
}

$("span#limit").countdown("2019-09-12 17:27:00", function(event) {
  $(this).text(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
  event.elapsed && finish();
}).on('finish.countdown', finish)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.min.js" integrity="sha256-Ikk5myJowmDQaYVCUD0Wr+vIDkN8hGI58SGWdE671A8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<span id="limit"></span>
<div class="div">
  Hidden content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to ensure that DOM (Document Object Model) has been loaded before execution of script. Use `document.ready` as shown below

```
<head>
 <style>
 .div {display: none;}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <span id="limit"></span>
 <div class="div">
Hidden content
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("span#limit").countdown("2019-09-12 16:00:00", function(event) {
            $(this).text(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
            }).on('finish.countdown', function() {
        $(this).hide(200);
        $('.div').show(800);

        });
});
    </script>
   </body>
```